# Why does the minimal polynomial of $T\restriction_{\operatorname{ker}(\rho)}$ divide $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. If we write its minimal as a product of coprime monic polynomials
$$m_T(x) = a(x)b(x)$$
then we can write
$$1 = \alpha(x)a(x) + \beta(x)b(x)$$
for some $\alpha, \beta$. And if we let $\rho = \alpha(T)a(T)$, then $\rho$ is idempotent and commutes with $T$, so $V = \operatorname{ker}(\rho) \oplus \operatorname{im}(\rho)$ and both subspaces are invariant under $T$. Let $A = T\restriction_{\operatorname{ker}(\rho)}$ and $B = T\restriction_{\operatorname{im}(\rho)}$. I'm trying to prove that $a$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ and $b$ is the minimal polynomial of $B$ and as a first step I'm trying to show that $a(A)$ and $b(B)$ are both $0$. I was able to show that $b(B) = 0$, but I can't figure out how to show that $a(A) = 0$. My question is: how can I show that $a(A) = 0$ *or* is there a better way to approach proving that $a,b$ are the minimal polynomials of $A, B$ respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Step 1*: If you can show that $b(T)$ vanishes on $\mathrm{im}(\rho)$ then you can show $a(T)$ vanishes on $\mathrm{ker}(\rho)$ by replacing $\rho$ with $\lambda = 1-\rho$, provided you check that you see why $\mathrm{ker}(\rho) = \mathrm{im}(\lambda)$ and $\mathrm{im}(\rho) = \mathrm{ker}(\lambda)$.

*Step 2*: Once you have shown this, the next thing to notice is that if $V = U_1\oplus U_2$ is a direct sum decomposition of $V$ and $U_1,U_2$ are $T$-invariant subspaces, then if $c(T_{|U_1}) = 0$ and $d(T_{|U_2}) = 0$, then the least common multiple $l = \mathrm{lcm}(c,d)$ vanishes on all of $V$.

Now take $U_1 = \mathrm{im}(\rho)$ and $U_2 = \mathrm{im}(\lambda)$. By step 1 we have $b(T_{|U_2}) = 0$ and $a(T_{|U_1}) = 0$, so that if $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the minimal polynomails of $T_{U_1}$ and $T_{|U_2}$ respectively, then $m_1\mid a$ and $m_2 \mid b$ and hence $m_1m_2 \mid ab$. But by Step $2$ above $ab$, the minimal polynomial of $T$ on $V$ divides $m_1m_2$, and hence $ab \mid m_1m_2 \mid ab$ so that $ab$ and $m_1m_2$ must be equal up to units, and hence if they are both monic polynomials, they must be equal.